# Timeout when calling azure-devops-api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

i've a nodejs api that use the package azure-devops-node-api. My api is calling azure-devops throw the package with usage of PAT to get a token on each call. I launch release on azure devops, get release status, ...

It works perfectly but on some request i get a timeout :

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.107.42.18:443

I retry same query and i get information without any timeout.

Someone has an idea, root cause, ... how to solve that.

Thanks in advance

Here an example of call to get status of a release.

First i've a method to get a connection token based on a path:

```
public async azureDevOpsConnectWebApi(): Promise<vm.WebApi> {
    this._authentificationHandler = vm.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(this.PAT);

    let option = null;
    // Force the non usage of proxy in local environment
    if (InfraPortalConfig.ENVIRONMENT === InfraPortalConstant.LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
        option = {
            allowRetries: true,
            maxRetries: 20,
            proxy: {
                proxyUrl: '',
                proxyUsername: '',
                proxyPassword: '',
                proxyBypassHosts: [
                    'visualstudio\.com',
                    'azure\.com'
                ],
            },
            ignoreSslError: true
        };
    }
    this._vstsWebApiConnect = new vm.WebApi(this.AZURE_DEV_OPS_URL, this._authentificationHandler, option);
    return this._vstsWebApiConnect;
}`
```

In local i'm behind a proxy. So i set properties to by pass the proxy for `visualstudio.com` and `azure.com`.

I've another method that get the token and call api to get the release:

```
 public async getRelease(projectName: string, releaseDefinitionId: number): Promise<releaseInterface.Release> {
    const _self = this;
    try {
        const vstsWebApiConnect: vm.WebApi = await AzureDevOpsHelper.getInstance().azureDevOpsConnectWebApi();
        const releaseApiConnect: releaseApi.IReleaseApi = await vstsWebApiConnect.getReleaseApi();
        const release: releaseInterface.Release = await releaseApiConnect.getRelease(projectName, releaseDefinitionId);
        return release;
    } catch (error) {
        LogUtils.Instance.error(`** AzureDevOpsReleaseHelper - getRelease ${projectName} - ${releaseDefinitionId}: ${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

It works 10 times but suddenly i get timeout for one two, five times, without any changes it works again ...

Can you give a sample of direct call to the azure dev ops to get a release information or queue a relase?
Or reference size, i've found nothing for nodejs call.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Had this issue, it looks like sometimes the node-API working perfectly and sometimes it fails with no reason, I ended up using the standard API which is more reliable. 
just for curiosity, could you post the code making you troubles ?

Comment: Thanks for you response. I've edited my first post with code sample. Have example to direct call the api ? :)

Comment: Yep..just like a thought, same issue.
I recommend work with the API, Hit me if you need some help with that.

Comment: thanks can you provide link to get sample of call azure devops api in nodejs. I need to get release and queue one. Identification will be done via PAT token. Thanks for your support

Comment: You want to get a release by name and quene it?

Comment: i want to get a release information bsed on its id (to see state of it) ... and also queue a new release

Comment: you need to get environment id in order to see the state

Comment: yes i know. But i search information how to construct the query for request. Example how to connect by usage of PAT

Comment: Ok, would you like me to share an example?

Comment: yes if it's possible :) I search also how to avoid authentication via a PAT when call from an api (not client side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

summary from comments and @Hugh Lin - MSFT answer, looks like there is an issue with Azure-DevOps-Node-Api,@Mattious asked to work with the API instead with the node-API library.
the following code snippet connect to azure-DevOps api with PAT and get all builds :

```
const axios = require("axios");

const PAT  = 'YOUR PAT'
const azureDevOpsURL = 'azureDevOpsURL'

const hash = Buffer.from(`:${PAT}`).toString("base64");
const Basic = "Basic " + hash;
try {
    axios
    .get(`${azureDevOpsURL}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1`, {
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: Basic
        }
    }).then(r=>console.log(r.data))
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an similar [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/235) with the same timeout problem.

One thing that could be causing issues is if there's a I/O bottleneck in how fast the agent can consume the data (and your dev machine absorbs faster than the hosted agent). You might be close to the timeout and that bottleneck would then push it over the edge. This is the idea of a contributor in this issue but not sure.

As a workaround you can try setting a higher timeout and seeing if this fixes it.

Comment: i've tried to increase the socket timeout in the header but it's changing nothing. This is the right parameter to increase?